# Using Harvard referencing style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, harvard-style

Can someone point me to some good instructions and resources on how to setup [Harvard referencing style](http://libweb.anglia.ac.uk/referencing/harvard.htm) (a.k.a. Author-year) with bibtex in a LaTeX document? The final formatting of the bibliography should look as in this page:
http://libweb.anglia.ac.uk/referencing/harvard.htm

I'm not totally new to LaTeX itself, but didn't use BibTex a lot, other than the default, predefined setup.

Answer (score 10):

The Harvard style covers a wide range of choices of exactly how to do things. Using the [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package has already been mentioned, while you could also consider [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Comment: `\usepackage[sorting=nyt,style=apa]{biblatex}` will give you more or less Harvard citations through `\textcite` If you're super lazy (like me) add `\let\cite\textcite` to your preamble to use `\cite` instead of `\textcite`

Answer (score 9):

try doing the following:

Put the following in before the `\begin{document}`:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
```

And then...

Use:  `\citep{key}` to cite into parenthesis, like --> (Sandwith et al., 2006)

**OR**

Use:   `\citet{key}` to cite in text, like -->  Sandwith et al. (2006)

Comment: If I try this and do `\citep{key}`, I get "(Sandwith et al. 2006)". I.e. the comma is missing.

Answer (score 6):

The package you want is here:  [CTAN/harvard](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/)

Instructions for installing packages are here:  [CTAN, packages, and online help](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/beginlatex/html/chapter5.html)

It depends on your tex distribution.  If you are using MiKTex, or another distribution with a package manager you just need to call the bib style as per usual and the package manager will handle installation.

Comment: It's generally better to use `natbib` instead of `harvard`.

Comment: And better to use biblatex than natbib? `:)` (Okay, it can depend.)

Comment: You can have your cake and eat it too: \usepackage{har2nat} - harvard.sty macros on top of natbib.

Answer (score 5):

An option as been mentioned: [\usepackage{harvard}](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/)

You can then use it like this:

```
\citeasnoun[p.42]{knuth} writes that TeX is great... 
In \citepossesive[p.43]{knuth} book we can also see something else.
```

Which would become:

```
Knuth (1901, p.42) writes that TeX is great... 
In Knuth's (1901, p.43)  book we can also see something else.
```

Comment: Note that there are several packages that offer the functionality of the harvard.sty macros.

Comment: is the `p.` in `p.42` necessary?

Comment: @pluton: Yes, the p. is supposedly required. Source: http://libweb.anglia.ac.uk/referencing/harvard.htm Under "Page Numbers" it says you should abbreviate with p. X or pp. X-Y (for range of pages). Technically, there is no enforcement of you writing "p.", so do what you think is right.