# Best style (.bst) for Harvard bibliography with Natbib using LyX

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, lyx, natbib, harvard-style

Learning LaTeX and using LyX. I'm using BibTeX and **natbib.sty** for citing. Which .bst is the best for Harvard bibliographies? **elsearticle-harv.bst** is the closest one I have come across. I have tried to tweak various .bst files for my purposes but it was really not intuitive.

But there are no parentheses around the published year and no separation (e.g. "," or ":") between the title and the volume and number information. I would also prefer Vol. and No. before the respective information but it's not a priority.

Comment: You might find that this answers your question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3730

Comment: @Seamus Thanks for your link! APA-style is nice and very similar to bibliographies made in Harvard-style. But there's, unfortunately, not any answer to my question there, still looking for a .bst-file created with Harvard-style in mind and working with Natbib.

Comment: The answers [_below_](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/using-harvard-referencing-style/3734#3734) the top one actually mention the solutions in my answer, so I still think this is a duplicate. What is wrong with the harvard style on CTAN?

Comment: Harvard.bst does not work with Natbib included in my Lyx-install.

Comment: 'Harvard' style is not a single bibliography style, it's a general idea (author-date). So you will need to point to an example of exactly the style you are after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If none of the answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3730/215) help, there is always the [harvard style on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/).

Otherwise I suggest you look into using [`makebst`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) to generate a `.bst` that behaves as you would like.

Comment: Thanks @Seamus, makebst is a very good alternative, but there is a high learning curve for beginners (like me), to get a desired result.

Comment: @socialli I don't think there's a high learning curve: all `makebst` does is ask you a bunch of straightforward questions about how you'd like your bibliography to look.

Comment: i have the same problem, so i used makebst, but my bst still dont work, it gives me a ? in the main text, where i put \cite and none reference at the end. someone can help me? thanks

Comment: @kah Does this question help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45132/im-trying-to-use-biblatex-for-citations-but-cite-returns-key-not-value/45133#45133 Also, is the `.bst` file somewhere that's visible to TeX?