# I'm trying to use biblatex for citations but \cite returns key not value

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to use `biblatex` and I want to cite something but if I use `\cite{key}` or `\footcite{key}` the author and title is not printed but the key itself is printed.

bibtex says there are no `\citation` commands

TUDreport.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt, nochapterpage,bigchapter,linedtoc,longdoc,colorback,accentcolor=tud9b]{tudreport}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{ngerman}

\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}  
\usepackage{longtable}  
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}


\begin{document}

Test\footcite{keyword}

\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

literatur.bib:

```
@BOOK{keyword,  
  title = {Werkzeugmaschinen Maschinenarten und Anwendungsbereiche},  
  publisher = {Springer Verlag},  
  year = {2005},  
  author = {M. Weck}  
}
```

But instead of:

> Test<sup>1</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 1. Weck(2005), Werkzeugmaschinen und ....

The Output is:

> Test<sup>1</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 1. keyword

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please provide a minimal example so we can see exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: We're going to need a little more detail to help you. The default behaviour is to print a numeric key. You have to specify a different cite style to have author or title printed as your citation. Could you post a little more detail on what your document looks like? Ideally, a small minimal example that illustrates your problem.

Comment: You have to run `latex` then `biber` then `latex` again to get the reference…

Comment: added some code. its 2. in the footnotes not 1.

Comment: works perfectly

Comment: @Seamus Can you expand your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 6):

In order to get references to show up, you need to run `latex` first. This will compile a document without the references. It will keep track of what references it will need in some auxiliary files. Then you need to run `biber`: this will look at those auxiliary files and then track down the keywords in the bibliography files and write other stuff to the auxiliary files. Then you need to run `latex` again, which will read the auxiliary files, and find the information it needs to turn `\cite{keyword}` into the right kind of reference.

In short, you need to run `latex`, then `biber`, then `latex` again. [There are tools available that automate this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64/215).

Comment: Maybe it would be relevant to refer to tools such as latexmk that eases this process.