# How to use HARVARD STYLE bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, harvard-style

I've just started using LaTeX in my assignments, and I've got some questions about the bibliography.

This are the commands I am using at the moment:

```
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{thesisref}
```

I need to arrange my bibliography in alphabet order using the **Harvard Referencing Style**, and I'd be really grateful if you could show me how to do this in LaTeX.

One other issue is "multi-citation". For example, Pennycook A (2010),"Writes the chapter", in Coupland N(ed), "the book name", "publisher", "year"," page number"
How can I show it properly in LaTeX bibliography?

I've tried to find related questions, but they still didn't fix my problems.
Thank you for your replies in advanced. Deeply appreciated!

Comment: Some Harvard-style modifications (for biblatex, mind you) were recently discussed [here](http://tinyurl.com/d9x9ge9).

Comment: I've provided a full template (many thanks to @Mico for the improvements) which includes a demonstration of how to cite and reference in the Harvard style [at this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453873/harvard-style-bibliography-and-referencing).

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a wealth of guidance on using Harvard style here. Try [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39454/how-do-i-use-the-harvard-citation-style) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/using-harvard-referencing-style). If you have specific problems, try asking a more specific question.

On multiple citations, the entry type you want is `inbook`, probably. How citations and bibliography are formatted will depend on the style.

Answer (score 1):

The [harvard](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard) package provides (i) various citation-related commands, including `\citeasnoun` and `\possessivecite`, and (ii) quite a few (seven, I believe!) bibliography style files that implement various bibliography formats and citation styles. Do check out the package's user guide, which explains the available citation commands and bibliography style files.

That said, it's important to note that you can use the harvard-style citation commands with non-harvard style files, and you can use the harvard style files with non-harvard citation commands. I hope this isn't too confusing; basically, what I'm trying to say is that one can use the citation commands and style files independently of each other. :-)

You mention that you're going to use the `amsplain` bibliography style. It would appear, though, that this style file is intended (mainly) for *numeric-style* citations; at least, the file's preamble notes that it produces "numeric-label bibliography items in a form typical for American Mathematical Society publications." As such, it may not work all that well with the citation commands of the harvard packages, which implement author-year citations. You should definitely consult the user guide of the harvard package for information on whether you might be better off using a style file other than `amsplain`.